# Java dispatch to child class when variable is of abstract parent class

Tags: java, types, dispatch

I have an abstract parent class `Parent` and six child classes `ChildA` though `ChildF`.

Another class `Other` has a six (static) overloaded methods `olmeth()`, one for each of the six child classes.

How can I write:

```
Parent message = Factory.returnRandomChildClass();
Other.olmeth(message);
```

At the moment I use an extra method, overloaded for the parent class, and six `instanceof` checks to work around this issue.  This is unscalable.

How can I get Java to dispatch on the *actual* type of `message`, rather on the type of the *reference* to the message?

Comment: With this pattern, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an abstract method in the `Parent`, and let each child dispatch to its own `static` overload:

```
abstract class Parent {
    protected abstract void send();
}
class ChildA extends Parent {
    protected void send() {
        Other.olmeth(this);
    }
}
class ChildB extends Parent {
    protected void send() {
        Other.olmeth(this);
    }
}
...
class ChildF extends Parent {
    protected void send() {
        Other.olmeth(this);
    }
}
```

Note that although the code in all six implementations of `send()` look exactly the same, the methods actually dispatch to six different overloads of `Other`, because the static type of `this` in each case is different.

Answer (score 1):

Use [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) pattern. Implement the `olmeth` logic  for every `Parent` child class and change your current `olmeth` method to this:

```
 static void olmeth(Parent p) {
     p.olemth();
 }
```